# google sheets form function not updating with data input from the script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having some trouble getting a function in a google sheet to calculate using values inserted by a script.

I have a google script that is adding data to a sheet based on user-inputted data from a form that the script has created.  So, in the form, a user inputs their name, selects a product and some options, and the script adds this to a sheet named `'Client Data Sheet'`.

I then have a different sheet which is supposed to do the math to calculate the price.  My script copies all the functions from a hidden template row into the next-available row, so, for example, cell D7 contains `='Client Data Sheet'!A4`, D8 contains `='Client Data Sheet'!B4` etc... These all display the correct values.

The problem is the price calculation function, in that same calculation sheet, which has a rather complex function that a previous coder wrote.  This function should calculate the price of the product and options based on the data in the same sheet.  It does so without calling a script, just pulling data from cells in other sheets, running some if() checks to decide whether or not to add extra costs to the total price, and adding it all up.

Problem is, it doesn't update based on the new data.  It just shows 0, as though the other cells were empty, even though they now contain data updated by pulling data from another sheet which was edited by a script.  If I go in to edit the function and just press enter, it re-calculates correctly, so I basically just need the function to re-evaluate based on the new data that is in the cells it's dependent on.

My theory is that it's not updating the function since I didn't directly edit the cells it's dependent on.  I could try to change the awkward, huge function this other coder wrote so it pulls from the spreadsheet my script edits, rather than from cells that copy in that data, but that seems like a workaround, and is unsatisfying.

TL;DR: a function isn't updating based on data that changes in cells that copy the data from other cells which are filled by a script.  Anybody have any advice for how to get the function to update?

EDIT: Ok, so if I make sure that the function that isn't updating pulls at least some data from cells that the script updates, it works. It seems that it doesn't recognize that the cell once removed has updated as well. It would be better, though if it was able to pull from the cells that pull their data from the cells the script updates.  This would let other users of the sheet change the products if a customer requested a change later on without having to edit my hidden sheets that the data is pulled from.

Code:

This copies a template row in my spreadsheet that contains the math functions:

```
function new_client(){
  var ss =    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Liquidation');
  if(ss.getName()=="Data" || ss.getName().indexOf("Liq")==0){
    var last_row = ss.getLastRow();
    var last_col = ss.getLastColumn();
    ss.insertRowsAfter(last_row, 1);
    var template_row = 4;
    var copy_range = ss.getRange(template_row, 1, 1, last_col);
    var paste_range = ss.getRange(last_row+1, 1, 1, last_col);
    copy_range.copyTo(paste_range, {contentsOnly:false});
    paste_range.getCell(1,1).setValue("NO");
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

This copies data from the form into a **different** spreadsheet, which the sheet edited above pulls data from:

```
  var clientSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Client Data Sheet');
  clientSheet.insertRowsAfter(clientSheet.getMaxRows(), 1)

  var lastRow = clientSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  var lastColumn = clientSheet.getLastColumn();

  var destRow = clientSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);

  var column = 1;
  for (var key in user) {
    if (user.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      destRow.getCell(1, column).setValue(user[key]);
      column++;
    }
  }
```

So, for example, after this code is run, the *Client Data Sheet* contains a cell, `B4`, which now contains the name of the chosen product, "foo".  The *Liquidation* sheet has a cell let's call it `A5` that contains the function `='Client Data Sheet'!B4`, as well as another cell which has the price calculation function: `=if(A5="foo", 100, 0)`

When the script above inserts the values from the form, the cell `B4` in *Client Sheet* **and** the cell `A5` in the *Liquidation sheet* will contain the right value, but the cell with the calculation function `=if(B4="foo", 100, 0)` will not update.

Comment: Can you provide your code? This would help us check the problem or how we can give you solution or workaround. Thanks in advance :)